# Flash messages are not shown after error redirects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, spree

I have an oldish Spree 2.0 online shop running on Rails 3.2, that I'm trying to customize with cleaner error handling, using

```
config.exceptions_app = self.routes
```

in my config/application.rb.

For debugging purposes I have turned

```
config.consider_all_requests_local = false
```

in my config/environments/development.rb

in my routes.rb I have:

```
match '/404', to: 'errors#file_not_found'
```

in my errors_controller I have:

```
def file_not_found
  flash[:error] =  'The page you requested could not be found.'
  flash.keep
  redirect_to :back
rescue ActionController::RedirectBackError
  flash[:error] =  'The page you requested could not be found.'
  flash.keep
  redirect_to '/'
end
```

I have tried several different ways of doing this, including the ones described in examples at http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Redirecting.html but always the result is, the flash message works if I specifically go to localhost:3000/404, but does not work if I go to some nonexistent URL, such as localhost:3000/asdfasdf.

In app/views/spree/layouts I have spree_application.html.erb, where I have

```
<%= flash_messages %>
```

which in turn is defined in/spree_core-2.0.10/app/helpers/spree/base_helper.rb

```
def flash_messages(opts = {})
  opts[:ignore_types] = [:commerce_tracking].concat(Array(opts[:ignore_types]) || [])

  flash.each do |msg_type, text|
    unless opts[:ignore_types].include?(msg_type)
      concat(content_tag :div, text, class: "flash #{msg_type}")
    end
  end
  nil
end
```

Comment: are alert are also now shown `flash[:alert] = "The page you requested could not be found."`

Comment: It does not make any difference which kind of flash message I try to display. They only show up if I explicitly type in /404 path.

Comment: You maybe need include helper contains this snippet in layout

Comment: I'm wondering if it has something to do with where you currently are in the middleware stack. It could be that flash has already been committed so any changes (the ones you're making are being thrown away)? Could be that since `/404` matches when you visit that route directly, it never hits the `exceptions_app` middlware.